# Синтаксический вопрос

Tags: синтаксис

Может ли быть составлено предложение по схеме [главн.], (союз + придат. условия), (союз + придат. условия)? К примеру, *Я соглашусь, если звезды упадут с неба, если это небо само рухнет на землю*.

Comment: Встретился тест, в котором утверждается, что такого быть не может, поэтому и вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

**Я соглашусь, если звезды упадут с неба, а это небо само рухнет на землю.**

Это СПП с однородными придаточными условия, которые желательно связать сочинительными союзами (А или И).

При отсутствии сочинительных союзов и повторении союза ЕСЛИ возможно неверное понимание структуры предложения,  а именно **как последовательное, а не однородное подчинение.**

Comment: Нет, если убрать *если* теряется нужная экспрессивность

Comment: Ну тогда пусть остается бессоюзная связь однородных придаточных с одинаковыми союзами, такая структура применяется в грамматике, например: Герой – это тот, кто творит жизнь вопреки смерти, кто побеждает смерть. Скажи мне, ветка Палестины, где ты росла, где ты цвела?

Comment: Но надо отметить следующее: читать такое предложение нужно с перечислительной интонацией, с подчеркнутой паузой между придаточными.